# MD5の結果が違う

Tags: php

初めて投稿させていただきます。
プログラミング初心者です。

サイトにログイン機能を実装するため、会員登録ページ、ログインページを作成しました。
ログインはメールアドレスとパスワードで認証するようにしています。

下記プログラムを書いてテストを行ったのですが、登録をした時のパスワードと
ログイン時のパスワードの値が異なるようでログインできません。。
登録時に暗号化したパスワードを用いてログインしたら成功しました。

入力パスワード:12345
登録時(register_check.phpの結果):d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
ログイン時(login.phpの結果): 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b

ログインしようとすると、下記のメッセージが出ます。

ログイン失敗
827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b

ネットで同じようなことがないか調べましたが見つけられず。。
基本的なことで大変恐縮ですが、ご教授頂けますと幸いです。

1-1)登録ページ(register.php)

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="register_check.php">
        <fieldset>
        <!-- Sign Up Form -->
        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="Email_reg">メールアドレス:</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input id="Email_reg" name="Email_reg" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="sample@fashionista.pics" class="input-large" required="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Password input-->
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="pass">パスワード:</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="confirmsignup"></label>
          <div class="controls">
            <!-- 会員登録 -->
            <button id="confirmsignup" name="confirmsignup" class="btn btn-success">次へ</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

1-2)登録完了ページ(register_check.php)

```
<?php
try
    {

    //ハッシュ化に使用する定数
    //$salt = "mwefCMEP28DjwdW3lwdS239vVS";

    $email = $_POST['Email_reg'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
    $pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);

    //パスワードはハッシュ化する
    $pass = md5($pass);

    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);
    $dbh->query('SET NAMES utf8');

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO Fashionista(Email,Password) VALUES(?,?)';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $data[] = $email;
    $data[] = $pass;
    $stmt->execute($data);

    $dbh = null;

    echo "追加完了";

    }
catch(Exception $e)
    {
    echo "ただいま通信障害によりご迷惑をお掛けしております。";
    exit();
    }
?>
```

2-1)ログイン画面(login.php)

```
<?php

//セッション開始
session_start();

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');

$status = "none";

//セッションにセットされていたらログイン済み
if(isset($_SESSION["Email"]))
  $status = "logged_in";
else if(!empty($_POST["Email"]) && !empty($_POST["pass_word"])){
  //ユーザ名、パスワードが一致する行を探す
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass_word'];

    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
    $pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);

    $pass = md5($pass);

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Email, Password FROM Fashionista WHERE Email = ? AND Password = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $pass);

  $stmt->execute();

  //結果を保存
  $stmt->store_result();
  //結果の行数が1だったら成功
  if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
    $status = "ok";
    //セッションにユーザ名を保存
    $_SESSION["Email"] = $email;
  }else
    $status = "failed";
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>ログイン</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>ログイン</h1>
    <?php if($status == "logged_in"): ?>
      <p>ログイン済み</p>
    <?php elseif($status == "ok"): ?>
      <p>ログイン成功</p>
    <?php elseif($status == "failed"): ?>
      <p>ログイン失敗</p>
      <?php
        print $pass
      ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      <form method="POST" action="login.php">
        メールアドレス：<input type="text" name="Email" />
        パスワード：<input type="password" name="pass_word" />
        <input type="submit" value="ログイン" />
      </form>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

申し訳ございません。簡単のためにソースコードを省略して書いていたのですが、どうやらそこに問題があったようでした。。会員登録ページについて、ページ遷移をせずに登録完了させたく、Ajaxを追加していました。上記のプログラムは問題なく動きました。質問にご回答頂いた皆様、貴重なお時間を頂いたにも関わらず申し訳ございません。

実際に不具合を起こしているであろう箇所は下記です。
恥を承知の上でもしアドバイスいただけるようでしたら、ぜひお願い致します。。

1-1改)登録フォーム
１行めが異なります。

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" onSubmit="send_register(); return false;">
        <fieldset>
        <!-- Sign Up Form -->
        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="Email_reg">メールアドレス:</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input id="Email_reg" name="Email_reg" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="sample@fashionista.pics" class="input-large" required="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Password input-->
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="pass">パスワード:</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required="">
            <em>※4文字以上20文字以内で設定してください</em>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="confirmsignup"></label>
          <div class="controls">
            <!-- 会員登録 -->
            <button id="confirmsignup" name="confirmsignup" class="btn btn-success">次へ</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

1-3) 登録完了ページを呼び出すjavascript

```
function send_register() {
  var register_form = {
    Email_reg : $(':text[name="Email_reg"]').val(),
    pass : $(':text[name="pass"]').val()
  };

alert(pass)

  // AjaxでPHPを呼び出す
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './register_check.php', // 実行するPHPの相対パス
    cache: false,
    data: register_form, // register_check.phpに渡すデータ。
    success: function(html) {
      alert("登録成功しました")
    },
    error: function() {
      // エラーが返ってきた場合の処理
      alert("登録失敗しました")
    }
  });
}
```

1-2) 登録完了ページ(register_check.php)
上記と同じです。

Comment: `d41d8cd98f...`は空の文字列のmd5ハッシュなので、登録時に`$pass`が空になっているんだと思います。`register.php`のformタグが閉じていないようですが、実際のコードもその通りですか？

Comment: h2so5様
早々のご回答ありがとうございます。register.phpは一部抜粋ですが、上記formタグは１行目〜最下行で閉じています。
空の文字列ハッシュなんですね・・・

Comment: すみません、閉じていないというのは`<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="register_check.php"`←ここに`>`がないという意味です。これ自体は原因ではないと思いますが。

Comment: ピュアパスワードだけをハッシュすると対レインボーテーブル脆弱性ですよ。せめてソルトつけましょうよ。

Comment: h2so5様
ありがとうございます。実際のソースコードを確認したところ、問題ありませんでした。。

Comment: 774RR様
コメントありがとうございます。
最初は下記のようにsaltつけていたのですが、うまく行かず原因解明のためとっております。紛らわしくてすみません。
$salt = "mwefCMEP28DjwdW3lwdS239vVS";
$pass = md5($_POST["pass_word"] . $salt);

Comment: 「登録時に暗号化したパスワードを用いてログインしたら成功しました。」とは具体的に何をしたのでしょうか。`d41d8cd98f...`をlogin.phpで入力したということですか？

Comment: unarist様
ありがとうございます。仰るとおりです。
$pass = 'd41d8cd98f...'として直接入力しました。

Comment: pass : $(':text[name="pass"]').val()と言う部分ですが、:passwordでは？詳しくないので間違っていたらすみません。

Comment: eripong様
ありがとうございます。
ご指摘いただいたようにしたところ無事動きました。。